# How to break out of a while loop and if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, webdriver-io

I need to break out both the while loop and if statement when the the value inside the if statement is great than 0, in turn the code should then break from the while loop.

How can I achieve this?

My code is as follows:

```
it('x Accordion description should appear after 5 seconds upon being clicked', function(done) {
      //this.timeout(15000);
      //setTimeout(done, 6000);
      var i = 0;
      while (i < 15000) {
          browser.click('#accordion');
          //var timeoutText = browser.getText('#timeout').length;
          var timeoutText = browser.getText('#timeout').length;
          console.log(timeoutText);

            if (timeoutText > 0) {
                  browser.pause(5000);
                  console.log("Pass");
                  break;
                  i++;
            }
      }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your loop is correct It should break out of while , The only thing I can figure out is that try to increment i (i++) outside the if condition.

Comment: thanks for your help @Akshay Aggarwal adding the i outside the if statement did the trick.

Comment: Upvote the comment if it helped you ;-)

Comment: Sorry im new to stackoverflow, how do I update your above comment? :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `label` to break out

```
 outer: while (i < 15000) {
    browser.click('#accordion');
    //var timeoutText = browser.getText('#timeout').length;
    var timeoutText = browser.getText('#timeout').length;
    console.log(timeoutText);

    if (timeoutText > 0) {
        browser.pause(5000);
        console.log("Pass");
        break outer;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help guys adding the i++ outside the if statement did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Would adding the condition to the while statement work?

```
it('x Accordion description should appear after 5 seconds upon being clicked', function(done) {
      //this.timeout(15000);
      //setTimeout(done, 6000);
      var i = 0;
      var timeoutText = 1;
      while (i < 15000 && timeoutText <= 0) {
          browser.click('#accordion');              
          timeoutText = browser.getText('#timeout').length;
          console.log(timeoutText);

            if (timeoutText > 0) {
                  browser.pause(5000);
                  console.log("Pass");
                  i++;
            }
      }
```

Also, if you don't need to run the while loop, this could be written more simply, for ex.

```
it('x Accordion description should appear after 5 seconds upon being clicked', function(done) {
      //this.timeout(15000);
      //setTimeout(done, 6000);
      var i = 0;
      var timeoutText = browser.getText('#timeout').length;
      while (i < 15000 && timeoutText <= 0) {
          browser.click('#accordion');              
          timeoutText = browser.getText('#timeout').length;
          console.log(timeoutText);
          browser.pause(5000);
          console.log("Pass");
          i++;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
it('x Accordion description should appear after 5 seconds upon being clicked', function() {
    // http://webdriver.io/api/utility/waitUntil.html
    browser.waitUntil(function () {
      // Your condition to wait:
      browser.click('#accordion');
      return browser.getText('#timeout').length > 0
    }, 
    15200, // Waiting timeout 15 secs, but actually only 3 clicks will be done
    'expected accordion description should appear after 5 seconds upon being clicked', 
    5000) // Pooling interval - each 5 secs
}
```